# Which is correct, 'While riding' or 'riding'?

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions

1. Riding across the battle field, he saw a large number of dead warriors.
2. While riding across the battle field, he saw a large number of dead warriors.

Which of the above sentences is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both sentences are correct and understandable.

A possible nuance is

> While riding across the battle field

gives more emphasis on the primary intent of "riding across the battlefield" whereas

> Riding across the battle field...

has more emphasis on "seeing/*surveying*  a large number of dead warriors".